# How to make a "distinct" detection on a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

At this time I have this very complex query that I loop through and I get something like this:

List of Challenges:

```
TEAM A
  - Challenge 1

TEAM A
  - Challenge 4

TEAM A
  - Challege 6
```

And I want to change to something like:

```
TEAM A
  - Challenge 1
  - Challenge 4
  - Challenge 6
```

My question is, since the query is a very complex one, maybe I could do this inside the loop but, if that's the case, how can we achieve something like that?

Can I ask an example case so that I can use, in order to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

**UPDATE:**
The query is something like this:
Translated:

```
public function listachallengesPendentes()
{
  $select = $this->getAdapter()->select();
  $select->from(array("e"=>"teams"),array('name'));
  $select->join(array("de"=>"challengeperteam"),"e.cod_team = de.cod_teamFk",array());
  $select->join(array("d"=>"challenges"),"d.cod_challenge = de.cod_challengeFk",array('title'));

  $select->columns(array("e.cod_team"
                         ,"name_team"=>"e.name"
          ,"d.cod_challenge"
          ,"name_challenge"=>"d.title"
          ,"d.details"
          ,"d.score"
          ,"category"=>"d.cod_categoryFk"
          ,"de.proof"
          ,"de.date_concluded"
          ,"de.cod_challenge_team"
       ));

$select->where("de.status = 0");
$select->order(array('e.cod_team DESC', 'de.cod_challenge_team DESC'));

 return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
 }
```

So I need to add a distinct some part :s :D ?

The foreach actually is pretty basic:

```
foreach ($challenges as $d){ 
//display the name:
echo $d['name_team']; 

...

}
```

**UPDATE 2**
The clean query (not tested):

```
SELECT e.name
,d.cod_team
,d.cod_challenge
,d.title
,d.details
,d.score
,de.proof
,de.date_concluded
,de.cod_challenge_team
FROM teams e
INNER JOIN challengeperteam de ON de.cod_teamFk = e.cod_team
INNER JOIN challenges d ON d.cod_challenge = de.cod_challengeFk
WHERE  de.status = 0 
ORDER BY  e.cod_team DESC, de.cod_challenge_team DESC;
```

Comment: You may show the foreach loop in question, and perhaps your query.

Comment: Can you post some code please? The `foreach` and the SQL query would be helpful.

Comment: It would be useful to see the query you're using, and how exactly you're getting the separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
$current_team = null;
foreach($challenges as $challenge){
    if($current_team != $challenge->team){
        $current_team = $challenge->team;
        echo $current_team, "\n";
    }
    echo $challenge->challenge_name, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to avoid the unset. I have update the post with a more detailed question. thanks in advance.

Comment: :) I've used a very similar solution. Something among those lines: foreach ($challenge as $c) {


  if($c["team_name"] != $teamName) {
    //show team name:
  }

// At the very end of the loop:
$teamName = $c["team_name"];
}

Answer (score 1):

At a very basic level, ie in the loop, you can just detect if the `TEAM A` variable is equal to the current (previous) value, and if so, don't print it a second time. This relies on the result set being sorted on the `TEAM A` column.

However, you can also do this in the SQL query, so if you can provide the current SQL Query, I can explain how you'd update it.

Comment: I have edited my question so that, perhaps you could help me with the query. that will be, obviously, the perfect solution, but I don't find it easy. :s

Comment: I don't know if you can provide the fully composed SQL instead of the `$select->` lines?

Comment: I've edited my question to provide a hipotetical (because it was not tested) query of the above. I do agree, that the Zend usage isn't at all, clean, and I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

you could store the array results in a multi-dimensional array like so:

```
$query_Challenges = "SELECT `Team`,`Challenges` FROM YourTable";
$Challenges = mysql_query($query_Challenges, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Challenges = mysql_fetch_assoc($Challenges);

$challengeResults = array();

do{
    if(!array_key_exists($row_Challenges['cod_team'])){
        $challengeResults[$row_Challenges['cod_team']] = array();
    }
    $challengeResults[$row_Challenges['cod_team']][] = $row_Challenges['cod_challenge_team'];
}while($row_Challenges = mysql_fetch_assoc($Challenges));
```

*EDIT*

looking at your query statement, the data should be already sorted properly by your ORDER clause, so if you just need not repeatedly print the team as shown in codeblock 2, then something like:

```
$team = '';
do {
    if($team != $row_Challenges['cod_team']){
        echo "TEAM $row_Challenges['cod_team']<br/>";
        $team = $row_Challenges['cod_team'];
    }
    echo " - $row_Challenges['cod_challenge_team']<br />";
}while($row_Challenges = mysql_fetch_assoc($Challenges));
```

you could easily substitute a foreach for the do loop, as long as there is a variable used as the "current team" and an if statement used to say "dont print the next team name unless its different than the current team name"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about the do while loop. I have updated my question with a more detailed case about what is in place here, if you feel like, please advise.

Comment: that is a pretty complicated query... what framework are you using? I think it would actually be more helpful to see the final assembled SQL query string than the function that assembles the various query components

Comment: Yeah, lol, the SQL composer makes it harder to read than an actual SQL statement. Fairly sure they intended it the other way around.

Comment: I've updated the question with a proper (not tested however) mysql query.

Comment: I believe, this cannot be done using mysql. No matter what. :D

Comment: well yes and no. You should already have the data sorted the way you want with SQL, but you cant write a query (that I know of) that would omit the duplicate team names from the record results - whatever columns you SELECT, they will always be included in each row of the recordset